# WSS Sharing Properties between Web Parts

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss, web-parts

Is it possible to share properties between different web parts? I would like a user to only enter there user name and password in one web part and it be accessible in other parts.

Answer (score 3):

I think that it would be easier to store the properties in the property bag of the page/site. Like this you could share them not only among web parts but controls as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by connecting the web parts. Look into implementing the complementary IRowProvider and IRowConsumer interfaces. [This article](http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/showarticle.tss?id=WebParts2) explains the basics and walks you though an example.